# I need a multi-language site with webshop functionality. Which CMS to choose?

Tags: ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I need to develop a multi-language site which includes simple webshop functionality. I have extended experience with WordPress. There are numerous shopping cart plugins available for WordPress however none of them is compatible with multi-language plugins such as [WMPL](http://wpml.org).

Drupal is an option I looked into (using i18n and Ubercart) and I am not sure this is the solution I am looking for.

Another solution I considered is to develop a custom WordPress cart plugin that is compatible with WPML. Anyone familiar with this situation? Any recommendation regarding CMSes that fit my needs? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've not tried it but I believe Magento has pretty robust language and currency support. I would suggest going with a CMS that is designed with eCommerce in mind rather then trying to get an eCommerce solution out of one that isn't designed for it. (It's possible to get a good webshop out of WordPress or Drupal many do but imho it's better to start with an eCommerce base if you want an eCommerce site).

Answer (score 0):

We are WPML's developers. We're using Shopp plugin (http://shopplugin.net ) and have plans to work with Shopp authors very soon to make it multilingual-ready.

WP E-Commerce will follow soon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what platform... I can vouch for nopCommerce if you're looking at .NET

http://nopcommerce.com